# Loading .tif / .tiff with fxml/javafx

Tags: imageview, javafx, tiff, fxml

how can i load a .tif with fxml or javafx ?

I tried this:

```
<ImageView>
  <image>
    <Image url="@bsp.tif"/>
  </image>
</ImageView>
```

but I simply get no response at all.

Thanks in advance,

Zombie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TIFF image loading is not supported by JavaFX 2.2 `Image` class.

To load a TIFF into JavaFX, you will need to:

1. Load the image using a library, such as a [Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) with imageio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/jai-142803.html).
2. The image loading library will probably create a Swing buffered image.
3. You can convert a Swing `BufferedImage` to a JavaFX `Image` format, using [SwingFXUtils.toFXImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#toFXImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20javafx.scene.image.WritableImage)).

Likely, it could be better for you to convert the TIFF to a different format using an external tool such as photoshop rather than to read the TIFF in Java and convert it to a JavaFX `Image`.

[RT-6038 - Native support for TIFF images in JavaFX](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090368) is currently scheduled for implementation in a post initial Java 8 release.